# always get error with jsnop in angular?

Tags: angularjs, jsonp

the jsnop file is loaded when check in web console. but also  i get "ajax Failed"

```
var loginuser = $http.jsonp( 'http://livegap.com/interior/users/login.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK', { params :{username: "username",password:"password"}});
.success(function(data) {
                    //$scope.myData.fromServer = data.title;
                    alert("AJAX Success!");
                })
.error(function(data) {
                    alert("AJAX failed!");
                });
```

login.php

```
<?php
header('content-type: application/jsonp; charset=utf-8');

?>

    [{
"loginUserName":"<?php  echo $_REQUEST['username']?>","loginPassword":"<?php  echo $_REQUEST['password']?>"
    }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change login.php
 Insert My data inside function 
that function get it's name from  $_GET['callback']

```
<?php
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');



    echo $_GET['callback']?>([{"loginUserName":"<?php  echo $_REQUEST['username']?>","loginPassword":"<?php  echo $_REQUEST['password']?>"}])
```